# Find all asymptotes of a function

Tags: calculus

Find all asymptotes of a function:

$f(x)=\log(x^2-4)$

Domain: $x \in (-\infty,-2)\cup(2,\infty)$

Vertical asymptotes are $x=-2$ (left) and $x=2 $(right):

$\lim_{x \to\ -2^{-}}\log(x^2-4)=-\infty$

$\lim_{x \to\ 2^{+}}\log(x^2-4)=-\infty$

I calculate the limits in +/- infinity:

$\lim_{x \to\ +\infty}\log(x^2-4)=+\infty$

$\lim_{x \to\ -\infty}\log(x^2-4)=+\infty$

So I'm looking for the oblique asymptotes of a form $y=Ax+B$:

$A_{+}=\lim_{x \to\ +\infty}\frac{\log(x^2-4)}{x}=\lim_{x \to\ +\infty}\frac{\frac{2x}{x^2-4}}{1}=0$

$B_{+}=\lim_{x \to\ +\infty}\log(x^2-4)-A_{+}x=+\infty$

The same for $-\infty$. How should I interpret this? There are no oblique asymptotes?

Comment: Yes, there are no oblique asymptotes. In general there are when $A$ and $B$ are finite real numbers. In the particular case $A = 0$ and $B$ is a constant, then you find a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: Thank you a lot. My calculations are ok?

Comment: @Gibbs: might as well make that an answer since it's the only one to give.

Comment: You can check there:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log(x%5E2-4)

Comment: Hint: you can test for the presence of oblique asymptotes using the following method:
If $\lim_{x \to+-\infty}\frac{f(x))}{x}=m\neq 0$

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I did not post it as an answer because it sounded more as an observation for me. Everything is correct in that solution. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: OP: I appreciate you writing out all your work and asking for confirmation of just the final steps.  All too often we get new users who paste their problem in and say "I don't know how to begin."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are no oblique asymptotes. In general there are when $A$ and $B$ are finite real numbers. In the particular case $A=0$ and $B$ is a constant, then you find a horizontal asymptote.

The computations are correct.

Comment: Thanks for doing that.  Questions with no (upvoted) answers posted show up on "unanswered" lists, but now this simple question can be considered finished.

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm function is known to have a vertical asymptote at $x=0$ and no other. (You can consider that there is an horizontal asymptote, but that has an infinite intercept.)

As your function is

$$\log(x^2-4)=\log(x+2)+\log(x-2),$$ there will be two vertical asymptotes at $x=\pm2$.